# Regular expression to replace nth occurrence of a word on every line in Textpad

Tags: regex, textpad

I have a file with thousands of lines containing comma separated columns.

```
'one',2,'three','hello','xyz',5,'hello','mnr','hello','axi'
'onae',2,'tree','hello','xyz',6,'hello','mnr','hello','asd'
'onee',2,'xdsa','hello','xyz',5,'hello','mnr','hello','aew'
'owne',2,'thr','hello','xyz',3,'hello','mnr','hello','az'
'ocne',2,'tee','hello','xyz',5,'hello','mnr','hello','zse'
'owne',2,'tre','hello','xyz',2,'hello','mnr','hello','aai'
```

Three of the columns in each line contains value as word 'hello'.

How can I replace the 2nd occurrence of word 'hello' with number 0 in every line using regex in Textpad such that the lines become:

```
'one',2,'three','hello','xyz',5,0,'mnr','hello','axi'
'onae',2,'tree','hello','xyz',6,0,'mnr','hello','asd'
'onee',2,'xdsa','hello','xyz',5,0,'mnr','hello','aew'
'owne',2,'thr','hello','xyz',3,0,'mnr','hello','az'
'ocne',2,'tee','hello','xyz',5,0,'mnr','hello','zse'
'owne',2,'tre','hello','xyz',2,0,'mnr','hello','aai'
```

Comment: Which version of TP are you using, which OS, and what RE flavor are you using in TP?

Comment: @Kennah: Textpad 4.7.3 on Windows 7.. how to check the RE flavor on TP ?

Comment: TP7, and I think TP6, use the ECMA standard, so there's no choice of RE flavor. However, with TP4.x, you definitely get a choice. I know it's in Configure, Preferences, but from there I cannot recall. I want to say that it's under Editor, but I cannot swear to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search using this regx:

```
(.*?'hello'.*?),'hello',(.*)
```

And replace using:

```
$1,0,$2
```

Make sure `DOTALL` (dot matches newline) option is turned off.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jC9oW0/1)

Comment: It works in the demo.. however, in Textpad, its giving -- Cannot find regular expression: '(.*?'hello'.*?),'hello',(.*)'

Comment: Sorry working on Mac today so cannot test it on Textpad. But I would assume regex is same considering I didn't use any advanced feature like lookahead etc

Answer (score 0):

I voted up anubhava's solution since that put me very close to the solution.

Find this:

```
^(.*?'hello'.*?),'hello',
```

Replace with this:

```
$1,0,
```